# sql transaction does not log when failed but the transaction still goes through

Tags: sql-server, transactions

My program registers everything correctly when all the requirements for the transaction are fulfilled and logs the transaction information.

But when faulty information is given the information is not logged but the transaction still goes through and I am not sure what I did wrong.

First up is the stored procedure the logs the transaction info

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LogTransactionAttempt]    Script Date: 8/1/2017 9:57:24 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogTransactionAttempt]
    (@ToUserAccountId int,
     @FromUserAccountId int,
     @TransferAmount money,
     @CreditorWithdrawl nvarchar(50),
     @TransferCode numeric(18,0))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Transactions (FromUserAccountId, ToUserAccountId, TransferAmount, 
                              CreditorWithdrawal, TransferCode, TransactionDateTime)
    VALUES (@FromUserAccountId, @ToUserAccountId, @TransferAmount, 
            @CreditorWithdrawl, @TransferCode, GETDATE())

    RETURN @@IDENTITY
END
```

Here is the overall procedure

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[performTransaction]    Script Date: 8/1/2017 9:57:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[performTransaction]
    (@ToUserAccountId int,
     @FromUserAccountId int,
     @TransferAmount money,
     @CreditorWithdrawl nvarchar(50),
     @TransferCode numeric(18,0))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FromUserAccountTest INT

    SELECT @FromUserAccountTest = (SELECT Count(*) 
                                   FROM dbo.UserAccount
                                   WHERE UserAccountId = @FromUserAccountID)

    IF @FromUserAccountTest <> 1 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('From Account Does Not Exist', 10, 1)
    END

    DECLARE @ToUserAccountTest INT

    SELECT @ToUserAccountTest = (SELECT Count(*) 
                                 FROM dbo.UserAccount   
                                 WHERE UserAccountId = @ToUserAccountID)

    IF @ToUserAccountTest <> 1 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('To Account Does Not Exist', 10, 2)
    END

    -- At this point we can log the transaction
    DECLARE @TransactionID INT 

    EXEC @TransactionID = dbo.LogTransactionAttempt  @ToUserAccountId, @FromUserAccountId, @TransferAmount, @CreditorWithdrawl, @TransferCode

    -- Check to see if sufficient balance
    DECLARE @FromAccountBalance  MONEY

    SELECT @FromAccountBalance = (SELECT CreditBalance
                                  FROM dbo.UserAccount
                                  WHERE UserAccountID = @FromUserAccountID)

    IF (@FromAccountBalance < @TransferAmount)     
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Insufficient Balance', 10, 3)
    END

    -- Now we can start the transaction
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        UPDATE UserAccount
        SET CreditBalance = CreditBalance - @TransferAmount
        WHERE UserAccountId = @FromUserAccountID

        IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   /* if errors - rollback transaction */
            RETURN 
        END

        UPDATE UserAccount
        SET CreditBalance = CreditBalance + @TransferAmount
        WHERE UserAccountID = @ToUserAccountID

        IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   /*if errors - rollback transaction */
            RETURN 
        END

        UPDATE dbo.Transactions
        SET Successful = 1
        WHERE TransactionID = @TransactionID 

        IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION   /* if errors - rollback transaction */
            RETURN 
        END

        -- Transaction
        COMMIT TRANSACTION

END -- Procedure
```

Like I said everything works perfect when the inputs are correct but if there is a bad input say a non existent account or lack of funds, it doesn't log the failure but the transaction still goes through

Edit
tried switching to 16 from 10 no effect

example of a correct transaction moving $100 from account 11 with a balance of $100 to account 22 with no balance

```
USE [Transaction]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[performTransaction]
    @ToUserAccountId = 22,
    @FromUserAccountId = 11,
    @TransferAmount = 100,
    @CreditorWithdrawl = N'credit',
    @TransferCode = 1

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

that correct entry returns

```
1017    22  11  100.0000    credit  1   2017-08-02 10:19:23.110 yes
```

in the transaction log

entering faulty information such as a transfering $150 from an account with a balance of only $100 raises the error codes properly but does not cancel the transaction even though the requested money is not all there

```
USE [Transaction]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[performTransaction]
    @ToUserAccountId = 22,
    @FromUserAccountId = 11,
    @TransferAmount = 150,
    @CreditorWithdrawl = N'credit',
    @TransferCode = 2

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

returns the following in the messages

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 3, Procedure performTransaction, Line 72 [Batch Start Line 2]
Insufficient Balance

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

So there errors are seen but the faulty transaction is not logged, but the transaction still goes through resulting in a negative balance

```
USE [Transaction]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LogTransactionAttempt]    Script Date: 8/2/2017 9:20:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LogTransactionAttempt]


(


  @ToUserAccountId int,
  @FromUserAccountId int,
  @TransferAmount money,
  @TransferCode numeric(18,0)
)

 AS

 BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Transactions

  (

    UserAccountId,
    TransferAmount, 
    CreditorWithdrawal,
    TransferCode,
    TransactionDateTime
  )

  VALUES 

  (
    @FromUserAccountId,
    @TransferAmount, 
    'Withdrawl',
    @TransferCode,
    GETDATE()
  )
  ,
  (
    @ToUserAccountId,
    @TransferAmount, 
    'Credit',
    @TransferCode,
    GETDATE()
  )



  RETURN @@IDENTITY



  END
```

Comment: Raiserror with an error level of 10 is probably too low to get caught properly. I'd try bumping it up to, say, 16. If you're not using a try/catch block, you might also need to set xact_abort on. That should at least prevent the subsequent transactions from continuing and committing when you hit your raiserror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raiserror does not set @@Error unless your severity level is 16 or higher. Messages less than 16 are considered informational, not errors. Try the following code to verify:

```
RAISERROR('Insufficient Balance', 10, 3)
select @@Error; -- will be 0
RAISERROR('Insufficient Balance', 16, 3)
select @@Error; -- will be 50000
```

Also, note that RAISERROR will NEVER break execution, unless you do something like raise a fatal error that causes the connection to end immediately (you'll need sysadmin privileges). So with exception of where you use an explicit "return", expect all code after RAISERROR to execute.

Read this for more about RAISERROR and breaking: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/483d6be7-6518-41c9-8138-aa1412ae8252/raiseerror-to-stop-execution?forum=transactsql.

In addition you need to

```
DECLARE @errcode INT 

after 

DECLARE @FromUserAccountTest INT;
```

the add

```
select @errcode = @@ERROR 

immediately after each raiserror
```

Reason is any successful event will reset @@ERROR to 0 - so all of the following resets your @@ERROR variable to 0;

```
SELECT @FromUserAccountTest = (SELECT Count(*) 
                               FROM dbo.UserAccount
                               WHERE UserAccountId = @FromUserAccountID)

SELECT @FromUserAccountTest = (SELECT Count(*) 
                               FROM dbo.UserAccount
                               WHERE UserAccountId = @FromUserAccountID)


EXEC @TransactionID = dbo.LogTransactionAttempt  @ToUserAccountId, @FromUserAccountId, @TransferAmount, @CreditorWithdrawl, @TransferCode

    UPDATE UserAccount
    SET CreditBalance = CreditBalance - @TransferAmount
    WHERE UserAccountId = @FromUserAccountID
```

Then finally change your first occurrence of

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0
```

to

```
IF @@errcode <> 0
```

leave the second occurrence as

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0
```

because it's testing the result of the update statement immediately preceding.

Comment: The errors do catch as when the faulty information is given, the error messages popup correctly, its that the transaction continues that I am having issues with and the faulty transaction does not log properly while a correct transaction does. How do I get it to log both successful and unsuccessful transactions while having it roll back any faulty transactions? I will try switching from 10 to 16 like you mentioned.  Coding is not one of my stronger skills so apologies if I am missing something extremely simple to fix.

Comment: what do you mean by "doesnt log the failure?" Are you referring to calling your [LogTransactionAttempt]? Do you mean it doesn't get written to your transactions table at all, or that it's indicating that it succeeded? If it's the first, can you please provide a minimal working sample with some sample data and table definitions for me to replicate :-) ? If it's the second, changing the severity level should correct the issue. Also, code indentations are helpful as well, in the future :-).

Comment: When the transaction has has completed without any errors it logs the information regarding the transaction in the table, that section works fine. Its when faulty information is introduced into the query, like an account that did not exist, the transaction completes but does not log, instead of rolling back the transaction and logging the failed transactions info in the transaction table.

Comment: As to the code indentations, everything is set properly in sql server management studio software but it doesn't copy for me correctly for some reason. Sorry about that.

Comment: So that problem, from what I can see, is not caused by any of the code you've included above. Is it happening when severity level is 10? If so does your transaction table have any foreign keys to accounts, or is something else causing an error in your insert transactions statement ? Another issue could be if you are using severity level 16 and you are calling [dbo].[performTransaction] from within a transaction. If it's not these I'd have to try and replicate to see.

Comment: Updated the initial post with an example of the procedure being run with a correct outcome given correct data entry and a faulty outcome caused by the transaction amount exceeding the from account balance

Comment: Can you try running     INSERT INTO Transactions (FromUserAccountId, ToUserAccountId, TransferAmount, 
                              CreditorWithdrawal, TransferCode, TransactionDateTime)
    VALUES (FromUserAccountId, ToUserAccountId, TransferAmount, 
            CreditorWithdrawl, TransferCode, GETDATE()), replacing your variables with the bad values you are testing Does it work for all of those values? Sry if you've tried already, but trying to eliminate causes for sure.

Comment: Thats what the first section of code is for, its a separate stored procedure for inserting the info (good or bad), thats the LogTransaction procedure.

I think the fault lies somewhere in the performTransaction procedure which is the second section of code.

When putting in valid information the program runs fine and the transaction is logged.

When putting in invalid information the transaction runs instead of being canceled and does not log anything

Comment: the third and fourth blocks contain the information regarding a valid transaction while the 5th and 6th blocks contain an invalid transaction

Comment: So regarding the fact that the transaction is still committing after setting error to 16, see my newest edits to answer. Totally missed that, but this has been good reminde.r

Comment: As for your logging issue, I'm stumped as to why it's not logging - the fact that you call exec (at) tranid = dbo.LogTransactionAttempt before you even check for account and transfer amount raises the question of why a a bad transfer amount would prevent the insertion of at least a row where success = null in Transactions. Besides going back and checking all your assumptions (each piece works, there isn't an active transaction enclosing exec dbo.performTransaction, ... ), I have no other ideas.

Comment: Alright that worked! Thanks a lot! Just have to make a couple minor changes and I will be good to go!